# How to Use Column Resizing With Nine Elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am fairly new to Bootstrap, and I am wondering how to use a grid for nine `element`s. I have a menu that stays at the top of my webpage, and it has nine `element`s, five `text`/`button` `element`s and four spacing `element`s (I found this to be the easiest way to get what I want), and by itself, it looks like this:

[image: Menu1]

This looks great, however, I learned in Bootstrap how to make my page resize depending on screen size. Here is what it looks like in the non-large version (with no resize changes):

[image: Menu2]

Now, if you know how resizing works (I would like to think that you do), you know that it only gets worse from here. I am wondering how I could use a `grid` to allow my menu to automatically resize depending on screen size.

Code:

```css
#menuBar {
  height: 85px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  position: relative;
}
.titleButton, #contactButton {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-bottom: 3px groove;
  border-radius: 2px;
  line-height: 2.5;
}
.titleSpacer {
  margin-right: 10%;
}
.titleButton, .titleSpacer, #contactButton {
  display: inline;
}
.titleButton:hover, #contactButton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 2px groove black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>CyanCoding | Home</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Montserrat|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "container-fluid">
        <div id = "menuBar">
          <center>
            <div class = "row-fluid">
                <div class = "titleButton col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-6 col-xs-offset-12" id = "homeButton">Home</div>
                <div class = "titleSpacer col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
                <div class = "titleButton col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id = "programsButton">Programs</div>
                <div class = "titleSpacer col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
                <div class = "titleButton col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id = "newsButton">News</div>
                <div class = "titleSpacer col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
                <div class = "titleButton col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id = "aboutButton">About</div>
                <div class = "titleSpacer col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
                <div id = "contactButton" class = "col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Contact</div>
                <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 hidden-xs"></div>
            </div>
          </center>
        </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

P.S I was really only changing the results for `col-lg` because I was viewing it on a large screen and figured I could fix the others later. It is much preferred if you could get the other sizes working in your answer too..

P.P.S When viewing the code snippet, it will likely look really weird. Even if you see the full page result, you see what happens when there are using nine `element`s in a twelve `column` `grid`.

Comment: You don't need `col-lg-*` classes since `col-md-*` classes are defined with the same number. I mean, if you have `col-md-1`, `col-lg-1` is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one way to achieve this:

Code:

```css
#menuBar {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.title-button {
  font-size: 30px;
  border-bottom: 2px groove;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5;
}
.title-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 2px groove black;
}
@media(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .title-button {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="menuBar" class="clearfix">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="title-button col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">Home</div>
      <div class="title-button col-sm-2">Programs</div>
      <div class="title-button col-sm-2">News</div>
      <div class="title-button col-sm-2">About</div>
      <div class="title-button col-sm-2">Contact</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wrPQwQ)

---

As you can see:

- I deleted the separators as it is not a good way to do this. If you don't want your `border-bottom` to fill all of the width, you can create a `span` `element` and apply the `border` to it.
- In sizes from `768px` to `991px` I applied a `media-query` to decrease your `font-size` because 5 `element`s in two rows don't fill all the rows. But, if you want the last `element`, fill all the last row just change your `class`es to `col-sm-12 col-md-2`.
- Don't use `<center>` tag. It's deprecated. [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)
- Don't use Camel Case for your class names, separate the words with a dash.